# Difference between char(x) in delphi and (char)x in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I have a program coded with Delphi 7 and there is this function `char(x)` (x is variable), and I need to write the same code in C# using `(char)x`, but I don't always get the same result,

So I printed all the characters `x =[1..255]` in Delphi 7 and C# and I found a difference in some numbers here is some examples

[![C# vs Delphi 7][1]][1]

So I want to know what is doing exactly `char` function of Delphi 7 so I can do the same in C#?

this is how i printed the two listes :
in C#:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) 
{ richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " I " + i.ToString() + " " + (char)(i) + Environment.NewLine; }
```

In Delphi 7:

```
for I := 0 to 255 do begin 
  Memo5.Text := Memo5.Text +' I='+IntToStr(I)+' char(I) '+ char(I)+#13#10; 
end;
```

the answer was that char in Delphi uses ANSI code page and to do so in C# :

```
char[] characters = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetChars(new byte[]{X});
char c = characters[0];
```

"System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetChars" uses ANSI code page
thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGZ8R.jpg

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to generate both of these files?

Comment: Looks like you're working with two different [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)

Comment: It is the same content, but interpreted differently by the text editor.  It chose code page 1252 on the left, Unicode on the right.  Which is an odd choice, maybe it was written as utf16 (two bytes per character, like char in C#).  Be sure to use StreamWriter in C#, its constructor accepts an Encoding argument.

Comment: for @John  C#   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + " I " + i.ToString() + " " + (char)(i) + Environment.NewLine;
            }

Comment: Delphi 7                                                                                                                        
   for I := 0 to 255 do begin
       Memo5.Text := Memo5.Text +' I='+IntToStr(I)+' char(I)  '+ char(I)+#13#10;

end;

Comment: @OMAR you need to show a [mcve] because how you specify the encoding while printing is also important

Comment: @phuclv that's the point ,i didn't specify anything, so it must be the default configuration.

Comment: Thanks Omar! Now we can also delete irrelevant comments. As you may have noted, you can also format code to respect CR and LF and use fixed font. You do it by selecting the code and then pressing the button marked with "{}" in the editor.

Comment: What matters is the code that you are trying to translate. Why won't you show that?

Comment: What you really should have included in your question are the actual output files produced by each application (e.g. as hex). The text editor screenshots don't show the files as they are, but only two _interpretations_ of them.

Comment: Also, you should have told us which text file is produced by which app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi, `Char()` is simply a typecast of an ordinal value to the Delphi `Char` type. In Delphi 7, `Char` is an alias to `AnsiChar`, which is an 8 bit character type.

In C#, the `char` type is a 16 bit type, typically representing an element of UTF-16 encoded text.

So you might translate the Delphi code to `Encoding.Default.GetChars()` in C#, but that is speculation at best. For instance, there is an assumption there that the ANSI locale is being used. In my view it's not possible to translate the code you have presented without more information.

I think it is quite likely that the right way to translate your code is not to translate it literally. In other words, you need to look at the broader code to understand the complete task it performs, rather than looking line by line.

Comment: This is wrong. The characters on the left is CP1252 and not Unicode because Unicode doesn't define characters in that range. The right hand side is clearly C1 control codes

Comment: @phuclv What specifically is wrong here? In Delphi 7 `Char` is an alias to `AnsiChar`, and in C# `Char` is a 16 bit UTF-16 type. Are you claiming that either of these statements is wrong?

Comment: thank you Mr @DavidHeffernan knowing that char is an alias of ANSIchar in Delphi and that Encoding.Default.GetChars() returns ANSI as well. that's what i did char[] characters = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetChars(new byte[]{X}); char c = characters[0]; and worked fine for Me

Answer (score 3):

C# `char` types are defined by the language standard to be (partial) UTF-16 characters, with potentially multiple `char` instances being necessary to define a glyph (the thing you see on screen).

A quick Google search shows that the latest Delphi version defines its `char` to be a wide Unicode character, equivalent to C++'s `wchar_t`. That is not the same as C#'s type, even though they use the same amount of space.

Also note that your ancient Delphi version most likely has the ancient 1-byte Ansi `char`, though I couldn't find an authoritative specification of that. For Ansi characters, their mapping to Unicode glyphs is dictated by mapping tables called "code pages", which you can switch at will.

Comment: C# `char` is not the same as `wchar_t`? Really? Why not?

Comment: Well for one thing, `wchar_t` is not defined by the standard to be 16-bit. On Linux, for example, `whcar_t` is 32-bit. And it's also not defined to hold an UTF-16 character. With those two limitations in mind, C++20 introduces `char16_t` and `u16string`, which are bound by the standard to be UTF-16.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. On Windows though, `wchar_t` and C# `char` are the same I believe.

Comment: That's also not derived strictly from the data type. There was a pivot point for the Windows API around Windows 2000 (which is built on NT, but NT uses the old format) of using UTF16 strings for their "wide" APIs, but previously the same data types held UCS2 strings. A 16-bit data structure is just a 16- bit data structure without any rules to define what goes in it. Contrast that with C#'s `char` which requires all `char`s to be UTF16, for better or for worse.

Comment: Sure, but in practical terms, when coding for any version of Windows released in the past 20 years, the two types are the same.

Comment: this isn't quite to the point. The characters on the left is clearly CP1252 and not Unicode because Unicode doesn't define characters on that range

Answer (score -1):

It looks like in the C# code you're using [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) while in the Delphi code you're using some extended ASCII charset because the output on the right is actually the [C1 control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_controls)

In ASCII 32 characters in the range [0, 31] are called [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). When the high bit is enabled you'll get a character in the range [128, 159] as in your image, which are reserved for the high control characters because some old software can't deal with non-ASCII character.

Unicode's first 256 code points are exactly the same as [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) with the control characters being left out, and Windows-1252 is an exact superset of ISO 8859-1 with the C1 control characters. Characters in a white rounded rectangle like that are actually control characters visualized by Notepad++. You need to use the same codepage when outputting

It's also possible that you're choosing the wrong charset in the editor as Hans Passant said

Comment: "in the Delphi code you're using Unicode" is not correct. This is Delphi 7, and `Char` is an alias for `AnsiChar`.

Comment: I know about Delphi though. Both modern and old.